# Why do I get duplicative messages to my content script only when I have the options page opened in another tab in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Manifest V3 Chrome Extension duplicating messages to content script when options page is open.

I am working on my first V3 Chrome Extension (pretty much done in fact). I've realized I have an annoying bug causing duplicative messages to be sent to my content script only when I have the options page opened in another (or multiple) tab(s). I have an event listener on tabs.Updated in my service worker that is sending a message to my content script on a *very* strict filtering rule. This is working as intended just fine, BUT if I have the options page open in another tab, my content script receives 2 messages instead of one. If I have 2 options pages open, I get 3 messages etc.

When inspecting the console of the background script it only shows one message sending. When inspecting an options page, I see the same message in background plus an additional message being sent. I tried tracking this down but not getting any hits that are applicable, and it doesn't appear that I have multiple instances of background running concurrently when I look at my service worker in Chrome Dev Tools. Option page sends messages to

manifest

```
"manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/favicon.ico",
        "192": "images/icon-192-maskable.png",
        "512": "images/icon-512-maskable.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Target Site Dev Tools",
        "default_icon": "images/icon-512-maskable.png",
        "default_popup": "pages/popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "pages/options.html",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "identity",
        "storage",
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "css": [
                "css/contentScript.css"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://Target-Site.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/contentScript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://app.Target-Site.com/Target/*",
        "https://api.Target-Site.com/2.0/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "images/*.*",
                "injectedHTML/*.html"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://app.Target-Site.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It means there's a mistake in your code that manifests when the options page is open. A typical mistake is to load background.js in pages like options.html. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question that includes the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm - your comment made me try something which I think resolved the issue. In my options script I have the following line

`import { makeAPICall, getAuthToken, storeAuthToken } from "./background.js";`

Once I commented this line out, the behavior stopped. I'm fairly new to this, but I wouldn't think that importing functions that have nothing to do with the listener would cause the listener to fire in a different context...  Is there a different way I should import these simple utility functions or do i just need to duplicate them in options?

Comment: Extract them into a separate file that contains just functions and no other code, then import from it.